# Duda con cin.get()

Tags: c++

Estoy ahora con las sentencias condicionales y los operadores logicos, y me surge el siguiente problema.

Si tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
string deporte;
cout << "Indica tu deporte favorito: ";
cin.get();
getline(cin, deporte);

if (deporte == "futbol" || deporte = "baloncesto")
    cout << "Te gustan los deportes de equipo" << endl;
else
    cout << "Lo tuyo son los deportes individuales" << endl;
```

El caso es que así sí que se me ejecuta correctamente, pero si por el contrario elimino `cin.get()`, el programa pasa directamente al `else` sin dar opcion a que el usuario introduzca los datos.

¿Qué hago mal?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no está en el código que presentas sino en el código que lo precede.

Una operación de lectura no tiene por qué eliminar el salto de línea que introduce el usuario:

```
std::string var;
std::cout << "Escribe una palabra: ";
std::cin >> var; // no se elimina el salto de línea
std::cout << var << '\n';
std::cout << "Ahora escribe una frase: ";
std::getline(std::cin,var); // Se lee una cadena vacía
```

La solución ante este problema se soluciona descartando lo que haya en el buffer de entrada antes de llamar a `getline`.

Si asumes que el usuario va a usar el programa correctamente y sabes que la operación de lectura anterior va a dejar ese caracter ahí colgado se puede optar por eliminarlo con `cin.get`:

```
std::string var;
std::cout << "Escribe una palabra: ";
std::cin >> var; // no se elimina el salto de línea
std::cout << var << '\n';
cin.get(); // Se descarta el salto de línea
std::cout << "Ahora escribe una frase: ";
std::getline(std::cin,var); // Se lee la frase esperada
```

Sin embargo se puede optar por una solución más genérica que pasa por eliminar todo el contenido del buffer de entrada y es usando `cin.ignore`. Este mecanismo permitirá al programa funcionar aunque el usuario se convierta en un mono que aporrea el teclado sin miramientos:

```
string var;
std::cout << "Escribe una frase: ";
std::cin >> var; // no se elimina el salto de línea
std::cout << var << '\n';
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n'); // Se elimina el contenido del buffer de entrada
std::cout << "Escribe otra frase: ";
std::getline(std::cin,var); // Se lee la frase esperada
std::cout << var;
```

Comment: Hola. Gracias por tu respuesta tan elaborada. Pero no me queda muy claro el tema de los saltos de línea y eliminarlos con cin.get(). ¿Podrías volver a explicarmelo? Gracias!

Comment: Es sencillo. `cin` te ofrece varias formas de leer el buffer de entrada. Cada mecanismo tiene sus propias características. Una de esas características tiene que ver con la información que dejan en el buffer de entrada. Cuando tu usas `cin >>` el usuario tiene que introducir un enter para que el programa avance. El problema es que esa instrucción no va a eliminar el salto de línea del buffer de entrada. Si no eliminas manualmente dicho caracter la función `getline` se va a encontrar con un salto de línea nada más empezar y por ello te devuelve una cadena vacía.